# Custom metrics in Apache Spark Ui

Tags: apache-spark, codahale-metrics

I'm using Apache Spark and the metrics UI (found on 4040) is very useful.

I wonder if it's possible to add custom metrics in this UI, custom task metrics but maybe custom RDD metrics too. (like executing time just for a RDD transformation )

It could be nice to have custom metrics grouped by stream batch jobs and tasks.

I have seen the [TaskMetrics](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.status.api.v1.TaskMetrics) object but it's marked as a dev api and it looks just useful for input or output sources and do not support custom values.

There is spark way to do that ? Or an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the shared variables support [1] built-in in Spark. I often used them for implementing something like that.

[1] http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables